# Disaggregate Table Over 2 Columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

If I have the following table

```
Hour    Clicks  Conversions
12:00   2   0
1:00    3   2
2:00    1   1
```

How do I write a SELECT statment that dissaggrates it across both columns, so I get:

```
12:00   1   0
12:00   1   0
1:00    1   0
1:00    1   1
1:00    1   1
2:00    1   1
```

If I can't do it with a SELECT, how do I write a stored proc that does it with a loop?

Thanks!

Comment: +1 interesting problem. Not a new one, but it took me a few minutes to think of the solution, so you get an up-vote from me. :-)

Comment: I don't see the point of the second column that seems to always return 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This assumes there will only ever be one row for any given value of `[Hour]`. If there can be duplicates, I would aggregate those first (I assume the source is already an aggregation of some kind).

```
DECLARE @x TABLE ([Hour] CHAR(5), Clicks INT, Conversions INT);

INSERT @x SELECT '12:00',2,0
UNION ALL SELECT '13:00',3,2
UNION ALL SELECT '14:00',1,1;

;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
    -- CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS s2 -- to double the rows if you need more
),
y AS 
(
    SELECT [Hour], Conversions, Clicks, 
    m = MAX(CASE WHEN Conversions > Clicks THEN Conversions ELSE Clicks END) 
    FROM @x GROUP BY [Hour], Conversions, Clicks
)
SELECT y.[Hour],
    Clicks = CASE WHEN Clicks < x.n THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    Conversions = CASE WHEN Conversions < x.n THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.n <= y.m
ORDER BY CONVERT(TIME, y.[Hour]), Clicks, Conversions;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most efficient approach, but might be enough to get you started.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    Hour            TIME
    , Clicks        INT
    , Conversions   INT
);

INSERT @T VALUES ( '12:00', 2, 0 );
INSERT @T VALUES ( '1:00', 3, 2 );
INSERT @T VALUES ( '2:00', 1, 1 );


DECLARE @Stage TABLE (
    Hour            TIME
    , Clicks        INT
    , Conversions   INT
);

DECLARE @MaxClicks INT;

SELECT @MaxClicks = MAX(Clicks) FROM @T;

DECLARE @ClickCount INT; SET @ClickCount = 1;

WHILE @ClickCount <= @MaxClicks
BEGIN
    INSERT @Stage ( Hour, Clicks, Conversions )
    SELECT Hour, 1, CASE WHEN Conversions >= @ClickCount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM @T WHERE Clicks >= @ClickCount;

    SET @ClickCount = @ClickCount + 1;
END;

SELECT * FROM @Stage ORDER BY Hour;
```

Comment: While unlikely (and I only know this because I am familiar with the type of data model), what if conversions are higher than clicks for a given hour? e.g. it's possible that someone clicked at 3:59 and purchased at 4:01.

Comment: Point taken ... I would imagine that your tally table approach would be more efficient as well.

Comment: I think so. But please call it a Numbers table. It is not tallying anything. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE ([Hour] TIME, Clicks INT, Conversions INT);  
INSERT @x VALUES ('12:00',2,0),('13:00',3,2), ('14:00',1,1); 

;WITH a as
(
SELECT [hour], 1 [unnessasary column], clicks, CASE WHEN clicks <= Conversions THEN 1 ELSE 0 END click, Conversions
FROM @x
UNION ALL
SELECT [hour], 1, clicks-1,CASE WHEN clicks-1 <= Conversions THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Conversions
FROM a
WHERE clicks > 1
)
SELECT [hour],[unnessasary column], click
FROM a
ORDER BY 1
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```